# How to build bar-chart with 2 categorical and numerical variables in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have dataframe with 2 categorical variable and 2 numerical columns, which represents negative and positive changes in percentage. I have a very specific task and struggle to do that via ggplot.
I want to plot  Model and Origin on y-axis and corresponding positive and negative changes bars (not mirror plot, separately), colours need to be defined by the models

```
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                  Model = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                  poschange = c(60, 45,34,56, 65, 44,40, 55, 35, 24,34,12),
                  negchange = c(-5,-2,-0.5,-2,-1,-0.05,-1,-3,-0.1,-3,-1.5,-0.9))
```

something like this sample, but not a mirror chart, I want them one below one, separately
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Y axis, `Origin` and `Model` are displayed. Bars are sorted by `poschange`.

```r
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyr)
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","Canada", "Canada","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"),
                  Model = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                  poschange = c(60, 45,34,56, 65, 44,40, 55, 35, 24,34,12),
                  negchange = c(-5,-2,-0.5,-2,-1,-0.05,-1,-3,-0.1,-3,-1.5,-0.9))
df2 <- df %>% pivot_longer(., cols=c('poschange','negchange'),
                    names_to = 'value_category')
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Groups = paste(Origin, Model))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(label_position=ifelse(value>0, value-5,value-8)) # adjusting label position
df2 %>% arrange(value) %>% ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Groups,value), y=value, 
                                      fill=value_category, 
                                      group=value_category))+
  geom_col(width=0.75)+ # or geom_bar(stat='identity')
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-100,100),
    breaks=seq(-100,100,20),
                     labels=abs(seq(-100,100,20)))+
  geom_text(aes(label=value,y=label_position),)+
  labs(x='Value',)+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position='bottom',
        panel.grid=element_line(color='white'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the only issue here is that bars are mirrors, in other words, they are tied, joined. I want them to be separate, firstly positive values on right side and below negative values on left side + USA based categories grouped on Top and Canda categories grouped below

Comment: Also colours must be according to Model categorical variable + pos and neg changes need to be different, like fully coloured bars = positive, bounded (with the same colour) but not filled bars = negative

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977155/how-to-do-conditional-grouping-of-data-in-r/72978298#72978298